# How to structure single to many relations in schemas when needed to extract only part of the embedded schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I will be grateful if someone could help me with a database design problem
I have Item schema and ItemGroup Schema, also User and UserGroup and so on...

I wanted to embedded the Users as an array inside UserGroup for example and then when I find some users I will also get their UserGroup information.

Something like that:

```js
const userGroupSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  Name: String,
  Users: [{ Name: String, County: String }]
}
```

The problem is that I get the entire embedded array of users for every search that at least one user meets the search. I only want the users that match the search criterion.

Does the only solution is separate schemas with single to many relations?

I don't think that complex aggregate functions are the answer

Thanks

Comment: does one user can be present in 2 userGroups?

Comment: No, is't single to many. 
One UserGroup to many Users

Comment: I understood that... my question was is there any chance to find one user in 2 different userGroup.Users? well, your goal can be achieved by doing manipulation in code. You can query `var user_group = userGroup.findOne({"Users.name": "nameExp"})` to get the userGroup object contains the user. you will get `user_group.Name` and you can use  `user_group.Users.filter(user => user.Name == "nameExp") ` to get the specific user data.

Comment: In addition to [aggregation array operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/index.html#array-expression-operators) you can also use `find` query [projection operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/#projection-operators) to restrict the array elements.

Comment: Thanks for all the help but - and please correct me if I wrong -  I think that all this solution will take longer than just define relations between two different schemas and just Populate UserGroup from a specific users I retrieve from the database.

It seems to me that I'm missing something when not using MongoDB with embedded documents